# Community articles search no results image and message

Tags: customer-community, global-search, search-layout

I am setting up a salesforce community (public site in this case).

Looking for a place to set a custom image and message when there are no results found.

Do anybody know where/how this can be setup?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the OOTB search result components. You will have to code your own or use an appexchange package that allows you to do this.